# Outputting data from within an object (JAVA)

Tags: java, console, output

I'm trying to output some data from within an object to the console. Seems to be working, but below the data I'm getting a strange message.

Below is the code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
 * The Circle class calculates area, diameter, and circumference 
 */

public class Circle {

    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    // Fields
    private double radius;                  // Holds the circle radius
    private final double PI = 3.14159;      // The formula for PI


    /**
     *      Start Constructors
     */


    public Circle(double rad) {

        radius = rad;
        System.out.println("The circle's radius is " + (fmt.format(radius)));
        System.out.println("The circle's area is " + (fmt.format(PI * radius * radius)));
        System.out.println("The circle's diameter is " + (fmt.format(radius * 2)));
        System.out.println("The circle's circumference is " + (fmt.format(2 * PI * radius)));
    }


}
```

The console output is:

```
The circle's radius is 2.00
The circle's area is 12.57
The circle's diameter is 4.00
The circle's circumference is 12.57
Circle@5115a298
```

What is the circle message?

Answer (score 1):

Give your Circle class a decent `toString()` method override. You're seeing the return from Object's default version of this method.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   /*  return a String that shows the "state" of this object */
}
```

Comment: I don't know what this means or where to add this bit of code? I'm not that far in the chapter. Haven't covered @override yet

Comment: @blnr: It would go inside of the Circle class. A System.out.println call like this, `System.out.println(myObject);`, is actually calling this: `System.out.println(myObject.toString());`. And for this to make sense, the object's class must override the default method held by the Object class (which is what you're seeing).

Answer (score 1):

You must have a System.out somewhere else that only has a Circle object as output. Then Hovercraft Full Of Eels' answer applies.

Btw: Math.PI already gives you Pi!